# Accepting timestamp as an integer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am trying to POST a json object to the rails app.

One of the field of this object is a a pretty much timestamp. It's saved in a 'timestamp' member in a model.

Rails handles well a lot of datetime formats represented by a string (as example I can send "December 24, 2015 at 9:46:24 PM PST" and it will work).

However, rails will reject an object if I try to send an integer (unix time) timestamp.

Is this standard behavior (or am I missing something)

Answer (score 1):

We can easily do this by defining like a proxy attribute in your model

```
attr_accessible :integer_timestamp

def integer_timestamp
  timestamp.to_time.to_i
end

def integer_timestamp=(value)
  self.timestamp = value.blank? ? nil : Time.at(value.to_i)
end
```

Comment: `value` may be a string (e.g. a parameter from a form submission), so you probably want to convert it to an integer. In that case you may also want to specially handle nil or empty string values.  `self.timestamp = value.blank? ? nil : Time.at(value.to_i)`

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I updated the answer, thanks so much

Comment: @HieuPham do you really need the ternary operator? `self.timestamp = value.blank? ? nil : Time.at(value.to_i)`... can't it be `self.timestamp = Time.at(value.to_i) if value.present?` That handles `nil` too.

Comment: @Mohamad: so we can't set timestamp to nil if we really want :), anw I got your idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your epoch time explicitly.

It can be:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def my_attr_name=(timestamp)
    dt = begin
           timestamp.to_datetime
         rescue ArgumentError
           DateTime.strptime(timestamp,'%s')
         end

    write_attribute :my_attr_name, dt
  end
end
```